# How to add a glyphicon to a dropdown menu link using the link_to helper (ruby on rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Newbie question here... 
I'd like to add glyphicons on the links of a dropdown menu using the link_to helper (ruby on rails app)

The code I've got is:

```
<ul class="nav_item pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <%= link_to '#', class: "btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle" => "dropdown" do %>
                <%= current_user.ownername %> <b class="caret"></b>
            <% end %>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "View Profile", owner_path(current_user), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-user" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_owner_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Evidently the `<li><%= link_to "View Profile", owner_path(current_user), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-user" %></li>` is my failed attempt, as it affects the look of the link itself... Any advice?

Cheers,

Comment: but your code looks good; nothing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write your html code for the first parameter as a string with the html_safe method.

```
<%= link_to 'View Profile <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>'.html_safe, owner_path(current_user) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a block. Something like this:

```
<%= link_to owner_path(current_user) do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
    View Profile
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Writing it as following chunk of code :

```
 <%= link_to owner_path(current_user) do %>
 View Profile <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
 <% end %>
```